# Understanding How to Build Go Source

Tags: go, build

I am confused about how to layout my Go project and then how to build it. I am reasonably new to Go and believe there was a time <1.13 where the GOPATH was important. I am using 1.14, so I believe I do not have to care about that and GOPATH is *not* set. I do not (for the moment) host my code on GitHub (which is something various articles assume). I have read a number of things, but it all leaves me more confused:

- https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies
- https://www.wolfe.id.au/2020/03/10/starting-a-go-project/
- https://talks.golang.org/2014/organizeio.slide#1

I have laid out my project according to this: https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout. (Except this project seems to use a Makefile. I do not want to write a Makefile. I believe this should all work without a Makefile. I really do not want to write a Makefile.)

Here is the structure:

```
/src
  /cmd
    main.go
  /internal
    helper.go
  go.mod
```

go.mod looks like this:

```
module mycompany/mymodule
    
go 1.14
```

service.go looks as follows
package main // this has to be called 'main'

```
import (
    "mycompany/mymodule/internal/helper"
)

func main () {
    helper.greet("Jenny")
}
```

So, if I am in `/src` and I run `build cmd/service.go` I get
cmd/service.go:4:2: package mycompany/mymodule/internal/helper is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.14.5/libexec/src/mycompany/mymodule/internal/helper)

Do I have to compile `helper.go` first? Manually? Surely not. `go build` surely should be able to build my entire project, right? Including all the dependencies. Could someone please tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Do you have a git repo I can pull the source code from?

Comment: [“How to Write Go Code”](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) walks through the process step by step.

Comment: 1. Note that "golang-standards" is **not** _any_ kind of standard. It is just one random project layout _far_ from being an agreed standard. 2. Read "How to Write  Go Code" and stick to it. Use modules. 3. How you group your code into packages is not that important, do whatever fits your current needs (an refactor if needed).

Comment: Some more: Use the official Go version, not the Homebrew stuff. Use Go 1.15. Make sure modules are on; inspect go env (GO111MODULE=on). Module names without a dot  "." are best avoided; use mycompany.whatever.

Comment: In order to get it work you should put helper in the folder `/internal/helper/helper.go`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `go build` without specifying file path, it will look for the `main` function inside any `.go` files at current directory to start. It doesn't build entire project. But it wouldn't be a problem in this case.

You're importing wrong package. The package name to import must be `mycompany/mymodule/internal` not `mycompany/mymodule/internal/helper`.

And to invoke a function inside another package, it must be exposed to outside.
So you have to declare the function `greet()` as `Greet()`